# Is there a complete set of equivalence principles for first-order logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

There is a sound and complete set of equivalence principles for classical propositional logic in the sense that for all propositional logic sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$: $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent if and only if through the application of these equivalence principles, $\varphi$ and be transformed into $\psi$.

Here is such a set:

**Double Negation**

$\neg \neg P \Leftrightarrow P$

**Commutation**

$P \land Q \Leftrightarrow Q \land P$

$P \lor Q \Leftrightarrow Q \lor P$

**Association**

$P \land (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \land R$

$P \lor (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \lor R$

**DeMorgan**

$\neg(P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q$

$\neg(P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg Q$

**Distribution**

$P \land (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

$P \lor (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

**Idempotence**

$P \land P \Leftrightarrow P$

$P \lor P \Leftrightarrow P$

**Complement**

$P \land \neg P \Leftrightarrow \bot$

$P \lor \neg P \Leftrightarrow \top$

**Identity**

$P \land \top \Leftrightarrow P$

$P \lor \bot \Leftrightarrow P$

To prove that this set is complete, you can show that this set of equivalences allows you to put any propositional logic statement into its 'canonical CNF (or DNF)'

My question is: is there such a (finite!) set for first-order logic?

My thoughts:

First, let's list some basic FOL equivalences:

**Quantifier Negation**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula and $x$ and any variable:

$\neg \exists x \ \varphi \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \neg \varphi$

$\neg \forall x \ \varphi \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \neg \varphi$

**Null Quantification**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula that does not have $x$ as a free variable:

$\forall x \ \varphi \Leftrightarrow \varphi$

$\exists x \ \varphi \Leftrightarrow \varphi$

**Replacing Variables**

With $x$ and $y$ any variables, and where the free variables $x$ in $\varphi(x)$ occur on the same place as the free variables $y$ in $\varphi(y)$, and where $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ are otherwise the same:

$\forall x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y \ \varphi(y)$

$\exists x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \ \varphi(y)$

**Swapping Quantifiers of Same Type**

$\forall x \forall y \ \varphi(x,y) \Leftrightarrow \forall y \forall x \ \varphi(x,y)$

$\exists x \exists y \ \varphi(x,y) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \exists x \ \varphi(x,y)$

**Quantifier Distribution**

$\forall x (\varphi(x) \land \psi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \varphi(x) \land \forall x \ \psi(x)$

$\exists x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \varphi(x) \lor \exists x \ \psi(x)$

**Prenex Laws**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula and where $x$ is *not* a free variable in $\psi$:

$ \forall x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \land \psi)$

$  \psi \land \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \land \varphi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \land \psi)$

$  \psi \land \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \land \varphi)$

$ \forall x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \lor \psi)$

$  \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \lor \varphi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \lor \psi)$

$  \psi \lor \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \lor \varphi)$

Now, using the Prenex Laws, together with Quantifier Negation and Swapping Variables, and all the propositional logic equivalences listed earlier all FOL statements can be put into Prenex Normal Form (is that right?) ... so I was thinking that maybe one could show that all FOL statements can be put into some kind of 'canonical PNF' (and here something like Swapping Quantifiers of Same Type would probably come in handy) ... but what would that look like?

On the other hand, the Distribution of $\forall$ over $\land$, and $\exists$ over $\lor$ feel 'nasty' to me ... I assume I cannot prove them from the others ... which makes me feel that there are probably lots of such other 'nasty interplays' that would require such a principle ... and probably non-recursively many.

Then again, completeness of FOL gives me hope that there is a complete set ... but then the undecidability of FOL makes me fear there is not such a set. I can't really wrap my head around as to which result would be more applicable here.

Comment: First, let's assume you mean a "recursive set" (i.e. there is an algorithm deciding if an element is in that set), otherwise we can just take the set of all equivalences that are true. Next: what exactly do you mean by "application of these equivalences"? There is a difference between there being an algorithm for deciding whether or not two statements are equivalent, based on a set of rules, or there being some string of rules that gives an equivalence.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Right; I just realized that I should have said a recursive set ... I just added that I want a finite set (actually, is there a difference? Of course, I *want* a finite set ... but if there is no such thing, I suppose a recursive one would be ... interesting).  And I am looking for the latter: A string of rules.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I know FOL equivalence is not decidable .. but it is still complete.  So likewise, I am looking for a string of equivalence rules that demonstrates equivalence,

Comment: Recursive and finite are not the same, the former is strictly weaker than the latter. Take for examples the ZF(C) axioms or PA axioms, this is an infinite list of axioms, but still recursive. An easier example (not directly related to logic) is the set of even integers: definitely infinite and definitely recursive.