# Are these quantified statements logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Every non-zero real number has a reciprocal (or multiplicative inverse).

The above statement can be expressed as
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \big( (x \neq 0) \rightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (xy = 1) \big).
$$
Am I right?

Now my question is, is this statement logically equivalent to the following?
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R} \big( (x \neq 0) \rightarrow (xy=1) \big).
$$
If so, how? If not, why not?

In general, let $P(x)$ and $Q(x, y)$ be any propositional functions of one and two variables, respectively. Then does the following logical equivalence hold?
$$
\forall x \big( P(x) \rightarrow \exists y Q(x, y) \big) \equiv \forall x \exists y \big( P(x) \rightarrow  Q(x, y) \big), \tag{1} 
$$
where the domains of discourse for $x$ and for $y$ on the two sides of (1) are the same.

Comment: Yes. See 'Prenex Laws' at bottom of my post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418148/is-there-a-complete-set-of-equivalence-principles-for-first-order-logic

Answer (score 0):

no they are not equivalent.
In the first statement i can replace $x\ne 0$ by $x+y\ne 0$ or $y\ne 0$ by universal specification.

Since the scope of $y$ is only the second part of the formula.

Comment: Wouldn't those replacements introduce an unbound variable? What does this mean for logical equivalence?

Comment: Exactly. The scope of the quantifier $y$ is different in both formulae. In the first $y$ is bound only in the second part of the formula. So by universal specification, i can replace x in the first part by y and obtain a fallacy. However in the second fomula y is bound allover. So i can not play that trick. The real difference is the scope of the quantifier.

Comment: Are you saying $\forall x(P(x) \rightarrow \exists y. Q(x,y))$ implies $P(y) \rightarrow \exists y. Q(y,y)$? That's not how universal specification works.