# Using logical equivalences to show $∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y((Dx ∧ Dy) → x=y) ⇔ ∃x∀y(Dy ↔ x=y)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to show that $∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y((Dx ∧ Dy) → x=y) ⇔ ∃x∀y(Dy ↔ x=y)$ using logical equivalences. My attempt is as follows:

\begin{align*}
∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y((Dx ∧ Dy) → x=y) & ⇔ ∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y(¬(Dx ∧ Dy) ∨ x=y)                 &&\text{((α → β) ⇔ (¬α ∨ β))}
                            \\& ⇔ ∃xDx ∧ ∀y∀x(¬(Dx ∧ Dy) ∨ x=y)                   &&\text{(switched quantifiers ∀x∀y)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y(∃xDx ∧ ∀x(¬(Dx ∧ Dy) ∨ x=y))                 &&\text{(factored out ∀y since no free y in left conjunct)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y(∃xDx ∧ ∀x((¬Dx ∨ ∀x¬Dy) ∨ x=y))              &&\text{(De Morgan's law)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y(∃xDx ∧ (∀x¬Dx ∨ ∀x¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y))              &&\text{(distributed ∀x)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y(∃xDx ∧ (∀x¬Dx ∨ ¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y))                &&\text{(removed vacuous quantifier ∀x)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y((∃xDx ∧ ∀x¬Dx) ∨ (∃xDx ∧ (¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y)))     &&\text{(distributed ∃xDx)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y((∃xDx ∧ ¬∃xDx) ∨ (∃xDx ∧ (¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y)))     &&\text{(rewriting ∀x¬Dx as ¬∃xDx)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∀y(∃xDx ∧ (¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y))                        &&\text{((⊥ ∨ α) ⇔ α)}
                            \\& ⇔ ∃x∀y(Dx ∧ (¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y))                        &&\text{(factored out ∃x since no free x in right conjunct)}
\end{align*}

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. The target wff (∃x∀y(Dy ↔ x=y)) does not contain $Dx$, but I can't see how to get rid of it, so it's likely that I've misapplied some rule(s).

N.B. My workings include annotations, but they are hidden by the scroll.

PS As Bram28 pointed out in the comments below, step 5 and the last step are incorrect. Apologies for any confusion. For my future refernce:

- $∀$ does not distribute over $\lor$, i.e. $\forall x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \not\equiv \forall x P(x) \lor \forall x Q(x)$ - the wff on the left says "for any $x$, either $P(x)$ is true or $Q(x)$ is true, or both" (any given $x$ has either $P$ or $Q$, or both), whereas the wff on the right says "it is either the case that $P(x)$ is true for all $x$ or $Q(x)$ is true for all $x$" (all $x$s are $P$ or all $x$s are $Q$, or all $x$s are both $P$ and $Q$).
- The last step should be $\color{blue}{∀y∃x}(Dx ∧ (¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y))$, i.e. $∀y(∃x(Dx ∧ (¬Dy ∨ ∀xx=y)))$.

Comment: What is the set of equivalences you have?  You need some non-trivial equivalences involving identity to be able to do this .. something akin to some kind of identity elimination inference rule ... but now as an equivalence. So something like $\phi(t_1) \land t_1 = t_2 \Leftrightarrow  \phi(t_2) \land t_1 = t_2$. Do you have something like that?

Comment: By thew way, that last step is not right .. when you 'factor out' the $\exists x$ you end up with $\forall y \exists x ...$

Comment: Oh, and  $\forall$ does not distribute over $\lor$. So step 5 is also not correct

Comment: Also not clear what happens at second to last step ... can you make more clear that there is a contradiction by breaking this down into smaller steps?

Comment: Thanks @Bram28. re your first comment, I don't think so. In the book I'm reading, the author says that we can express the claim "there are exactly $n$ dogs" as the conjunction of "there are at least $n$ dogs" and "there are at most $n$ dogs", so as $∃xDx ∧ ∀x∀y((Dx ∧ Dy) → x=y)$ (where $Dx$: $x$ is a dog), and that this can be rewritten as $∃x∀y(Dy ↔ x=y)$. So, I wondered if I could show that these two wffs are equivalent.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=wlL2GHt1gS8C&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=%22by+taking+the+conjunction+of+these+two+claims%22&source=bl&ots=ZAizAUW-lP&sig=ACfU3U3juE9Xce05GjGbOuN8LPqmwKxd1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFlJHV09OCAxU2b2wGHRMWBhMQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22by%20taking%20the%20conjunction%20of%20these%20two%20claims%22&f=false) to the relevant pages of the book. See the bottom of page 323 and eq. 13.8 on page 324.

Comment: I have added a step before the second last step to clarify the contradiction.

Comment: Yes, the statements are equivalence, but just because two statements are equivalent doesn't mean that whatever equivalence rules you have are powerful enough to actually demonstrate that equivalence.

Comment: That's interesting, is this something that is peculiar to predicate logic? Because in propositional logic, we seem to always be able to use equivalence rules to explain equivalence between complex wffs.

Comment: Just made a post talking about some of these things ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two statements are equivalent, but it is really hard to demonstrate that using first-order logic equivalence principles. Indeed, the 'typical' set of rules (quantifier negation, quantifier distribution, null quantification, swapping quantifiers, replacing variables, various prenex laws) is not sufficient to transform the one statement into the other.

For propositional logic it is easy to find a set of equivalence rules that, together, can demonstrate any equivalence. If we have such a set, we say the set is *complete*. Indeed, for most textbooks it turns out that the equivalences rules they list for propositional logic are complete.

This, however, is not true for first-order logic. For example, good luck transforming $$\exists x \ P(x) \land \forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$$ into $$\exists x \ P(x) \land \forall x (P(x) \to Q(x)) \land \exists x \ Q(x)$$ I am pretty sure the 'usual candidates' listed above are simply not sufficient to make this transformation. Indeed, I am pretty sure that the equivalence principles that textbooks list for first-order logic are *not* complete.

Is there a complete set of equivalence principles for first-order logic?  I am pretty sure there is, given that there is a complete set of inference rules for first-order logic, and I am sure there is some way to turn that into a bunch of equivalence rules. For example: we could take a simple inference rule like Modus Ponens, and turn it into an equivalence rule $P \land (P \to Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land (P \to Q) \land Q$ ... but now tyou have to do this for rules involving quantifiers. And  since there all kinds of constraints on the use of quantifier inference rules, you will get similar constraints on the use of the corresponding equivalence rules ... In sum, this is not going to look very nice at all!

Now, maybe there is some relative 'clean and easy' but still complete set of equivalence rules for First-order logic, but is there is, I have never sen one, and a question to that effect that I posted here][1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418148/is-there-a-complete-set-of-equivalence-principles-for-first-order-logic) generated no responses.

Comment: Thank you @Bram28. is the lack of completeness in first-order logic due to the fact that first-order logic attempts to capture the *inner* structure of a proposition, whereas this structure is ignored in propositional logic?

Comment: Sorry, I think I have misread your answer. Just to confirm, by "complete" are you referring to functional completeness?

Comment: @user51462 No. Functional completeness is expressive completeness. I am talking about *derivational* (or inferential) completeness.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @Bram28, I haven't come across the latter concept yet. Hopefully I can revisit this question once I have a better handle on FOL.

Comment: @user51462 Well, it is exactly what you said in an earlier comment: for Propositional logic we can explain any equivalence using equivalences rules (as typically given in a textbook). For FOL this is no longer the case (again, as far as the equivalence rules go as typically given by textbooks)

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia page on Completeness: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic) . It mentions functional completeness that you referred to, but the sense of completeness I talk about is more like Strong Completeness, although it is not going from a set of statements to one other using inference rules, but rather going back and forth between two statements using equivalence rules. And like I said, I am pretty sure there is a complete set of equivalence rules for FOL, but it will be convoluted and unnatural … the typical set of FOL equivalences given by textbooks is not complete

Comment: I understand, thank you @Bram28.